# End to end alignment of 3 Columns using Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am new to bootstrap. I tried aligning three sections end to end (horizontal manner) with equal space. (1st column should be aligned to extreme left of the container and last should be aligned to extreme right.) There is extra space at the third column. I have added bootstrap css and other files and the code which i have used is mentioned below.

```
        <div class="container"> 
    <div class="row"> 
    <div class="col-md-4"> 
    <div class="col-md-11"> 
    <h1>Head 1</h1> </div> 
    </div> 
    <div class="col-md-4"> 
    <div class="col-md-11"> 
    <h1>Head 2</h1> 
    </div> 
    </div> 
    <div class="col-md-4"> 
    <div class="col-md-11"> 
    <h1>Head 3</h1> 
    </div> 
    </div> 
    </div> 
    </div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `text-align` property for alignment. No need to have `col-md-11` wrapped inside it.

```css
.col-md-4:last-child {
  text-align: right;
}
.col-md-4:nth-child(2) {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4">
      <div class="col-md-11"> <!-- Remove -->
        <h1>Head 1</h1> 
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4">
      <div class="col-md-11"> <!-- Remove -->
        <h1>Head 2</h1> 
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4">
      <div class="col-md-11"> <!-- Remove -->
        <h1>Head 3</h1> 
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you Manoj. Just now i understood no need to add col-md-11.

Comment: Welcome, Aiswarya! :)